# Can a caster hit themself with a Blast spell?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells

Can a caster hit themself with a Blast spell?
i.e. the usual example is the caster is in square A, casts a `Blast 2` spell, so they could hit BCFG, FGJK, EFIJ, etc.

```
A  B  C  D 

E  F  G  H

I  J  K  L
```

But what if they were in square F ... could they cast the spell in A and hit FGIJ?

Comment: See also: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3448/with-arcane-reach-can-you-thunderwave-yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Only with Arcane Reach**

[Blasts](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=125) originate from the caster's square:

> A blast fills an area adjacent to you that is a specified number of squares on a side.

Since you are not adjacent to yourself, you cannot target yourself by default.

However, with [arcane reach](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=310):

> Benefit: When using a close arcane attack power, you can choose a square within 2 squares of yours as the origin square. The power still follows the rules for close attacks.

You may absolutely use a square within two squares such that you are caught in the blast. When combined with thunder or psychic resistance, this is a fantastic way to use thunderwave or beguiling strands to rocketjump.