# Can a caster self-target with an attack power?

Tags: dnd-4e

Following on from a thought from [With Arcane Reach can you thunderwave yourself](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3448/with-arcane-reach-can-you-thunderwave-yourself/3453#comment24012_3453) I pondered if a caster can self-target with an attack power?

I'll restrict this to 4e as an answer, but my experience with the system is very limited, but the answer interests me for comical value if nothing else.

Related is [Can a caster hit themself with a blast spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14472/can-a-caster-hit-themself-with-a-blast-spell)

Plus @Brian suggested I ask this too ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in 4e the answer is **Yes. Depending on the target line**.

Many of a casters' At-Will and Encounter powers will have a target line of "one creature in range" or "All creatures in burst" or something. The important word is creature, rather than enemy or ally. Another wording is "You and all allies" or "you or one ally" these both allow self targeting. however just Ally does not.

Thus if your square is a valid square for a target (unmodified close attacks typically cannot attack your own square), then you can target yourself.

4e does not have any kind concentration mechanic for casters so taking damage/getting targetted disrupting a spell is not a concern here.